# Magento2: Create customers programmatically and associate to multiple websites

Tags: magento2, customer, programmatically

I have written a customer import which works just fine.
Now the requirement has changed .. the Magento instance runs now multiple stores / websites and i need to change the customer import so that the imported customers will get access to all stores.

What would be the best way to achieve that?
Do I really need to loop through all websites and create a separate customer for each of them? Or is it somehow possible to create global customers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the required scope.

Default behavior is that customers in different stores under same website can be shared. So you allocate website ID based on this. Customer can log in different stores using same credentials.

If however customers need to work on different stores in different websites you must create new customer records.

Comment: Too bad :( It would be nice without the redundant data